# Paramiko script with error

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, paramiko

I've found the following script on internet:

```
    import paramiko
    from paramiko import client


class ssh:
client = None

def __init__(self, address, username, password):
    # Let the user know we're connecting to the server
    print("Connecting to server.")
    # Create a new SSH client
    self.client = client.SSHClient()
    # The following line is required if you want the script to be able to access a server that's not yet in the known_hosts file
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
    # Make the connection
    self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)

def sendCommand(self, command):
    # Check if connection is made previously
    if (self.client):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
        while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
            # Print stdout data when available
            if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                # Retrieve the first 1024 bytes
                alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                while stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    # Retrieve the next 1024 bytes
                    alldata += stdout.channel.recv(1024)

                # Print as string with utf8 encoding
                print(str(alldata, "utf8"))
    else:
        print("Connection not opened.")


 paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko.log') # <----- added line
 connessione = ssh("10.76.80.11","pi","raspberry")

 connessione.sendCommand("arp -a")
```

I would like to send a commando to my raspberry with this script, I tried to run the program without the line:

```
    paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko.log')
```

but when I tried to run the code I've got this runtime error:

```
     /usr/bin/python /Users/Marco/PycharmProjects/ssh_control/ssh.py
     Connecting to server.
     No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/Marco/PycharmProjects/ssh_control/ssh.py", line 43, in <module>
     connessione = ssh("10.76.80.11","pi","raspberry")
     File "/Users/Marco/PycharmProjects/ssh_control/ssh.py", line 16, in __init__
     self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)
     File "/Users/Marco/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 338, in connect
      t.start_client()
     File "/Users/Marco/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-    packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 493, in start_client
     raise e
     AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'resolve'

      Process finished with exit code 1
```

So I searched on Internet and I found that the problem could be fixed with the paramiko.log line.

But now I've another error:

```
    /usr/bin/python /Users/Marco/PycharmProjects/ssh_control/ssh.py
    Connecting to server.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/Marco/PycharmProjects/ssh_control/ssh.py", line 38, in <module>
     connessione = ssh("10.76.80.11","pi","raspberry")
    File "/Users/Marco/PycharmProjects/ssh_control/ssh.py", line 16, in     __init__
    self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password,   look_for_keys=False)
    File "/Users/Marco/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site- packages/paramiko/client.py", line 338, in connect
    t.start_client()
    File "/Users/Marco/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 493, in start_client
raise e
    AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'resolve'

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can someone helps me please? because I can't understand where is the error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to upgrade setuptools and then re-install the package.  Seems the older version breaks something on installing the python cryptography package.

Try the following...

```
pip install -U setuptools
pin install -U paramiko
```

https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2853

Comment: Thanks for you help, I've installed again the module now there aren't errors, but the program still not working.  When I'm running the program with the command "reboot" nothing happen, I think there is some problem in the sendCommand()

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this:

```
   # Make the connection
    self.client.connect(address, port = 22, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)
```

because the port before wasn't specificate